# Generating LaTeX tables instead of text in Rstudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I am new to latex, and would like to generate PDF tables instead of text so my example is:

in my `METHOD.tex` file I have this text:

In the first group there were: `AAA`: items: `BBB`: items2 and: `CCC`: items3. We assessed: `EEE`: implementations. Of the total: `VVV`: objects to the survey before replying: `X111` :, rejected: `X222`

So `AAA, BBB, CCC`.... are object in which I stored numbers.

```
a1<-200
b1<-450
c1<-500
d1<-1500
```

so now I have used this code:

```
df<-data.frame(AAA,BBB,CCC,EEE)
```

Than I wrote:

```
df <- scan("METHOD.tex", character(0), sep="\n", quiet=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

And used following code (because I am generating more different reports and the numbers are changing):

```
df <- gsub(pattern=":AAA:", replacement=a1, x=df)
df <- gsub(pattern=":BBB:", replacement=b1, x=df)
...
```

Finnaly I used this:

```
df<- capture.output(Hmisc::latex(df, caption="Table", rowlabel="", file="", where="H"))
```

But when I would like to generate the table instead of text nothing happens. There is still AAA, BBB, CCC.
So I am missing something in last part of the code.

Comment: You should check out the [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) package to integrate `latex` and `r` more easily, as well as [xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/) to produce latex-formatted tables

Comment: also, note that you are not using `capture.output()` properly. You should not assign its result to `df`. Instead, just add a `file` argument with the name of the file you want the output in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R markdown in R Studio makes this sort of thing much nicer. Blocks of R code can be declared with three backticks`{r}code` and then inline code with a single backtick and `r`.

The following does something similar to what you want.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "user"
date: "Tuesday, May 05, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r}
require(xtable)
a1<-200
b1<-450
c1<-500
d1<-1500
```

In the first group there were: `r a1` items: `r b1` items2 and: `r c1` items3. We assessed: EEE: implementations. Of the total: VVV: objects to the survey before replying: X111 :, rejected: X222

```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
data(mtcars)
out <- xtable(head(mtcars), caption = "Head of mtcars data set", label = "mt_head")
print(out, comment = FALSE)
```
````

This generates the following output into a tex file

```
% Excised preamble
\begin{document}
% Excised ECHO 
In the first group there were: 200 items: 450 items2 and: 500 items3. We
assessed: EEE: implementations. Of the total: VVV: objects to the survey
before replying: X111 :, rejected: X222

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb \\ 
  \hline
Mazda RX4 & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.62 & 16.46 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 4.00 & 4.00 \\ 
  Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.88 & 17.02 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 4.00 & 4.00 \\ 
  Datsun 710 & 22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 & 3.85 & 2.32 & 18.61 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 4.00 & 1.00 \\ 
  Hornet 4 Drive & 21.40 & 6.00 & 258.00 & 110.00 & 3.08 & 3.21 & 19.44 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 3.00 & 1.00 \\ 
  Hornet Sportabout & 18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 175.00 & 3.15 & 3.44 & 17.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 3.00 & 2.00 \\ 
  Valiant & 18.10 & 6.00 & 225.00 & 105.00 & 2.76 & 3.46 & 20.22 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 3.00 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Head of mtcars data set} 
\label{mt_head}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And automatically compiles a pdf from the tex file.

Comment: is it possible to store this code to tex. file as I already generated pdf report with histograms (I used 'CairoPDF', '\\begin{figure}[H]') and would like to conbine it so this table would be my table in first page out of 15.